# how to change image on tap in table view for iphone

Tags: iphone

i have a imageView in table cell now i want to chnage image on tap how to do that

```
 switch(indexPath.section)
case 0:  

    CGRect frame;


       frame= CGRectMake(20 ,10, 270, 180);//277 182
       UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
       myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Abe1.jpg"];// abe2, abe3.png


       myImageView.frame = frame;
       //UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bowl.png"]];
       [cell.contentView addSubview: myImageView];
       [myImageView release];
```

how to change image on tap ( abe1.png,abe2.png,abe3.png)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following following:

```
// This will check if the user had started to touch something
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    //Checks if the user touched your image.
    if([[touch view] == myImageView) {
        //Make a integer that will keep track of which image your on. Initialize at zero for Abe1.
        if(counter == 0) {
           myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Abe2.jpg"]; 
           counter = 1;
        }
        else if(counter == 1) {
           myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Abe3.jpg"]; 
           counter = 2;
        }
        else if(counter == 2) {
           myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Abe1.jpg"]; 
           counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry I forgot it was a tableview. To check which one is the correct cell do the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];   
    if (row == 0){
        if(counter == 0) {
           myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Abe2.jpg"]; 
           counter = 1;
       }
        else if(counter == 1) {
           myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Abe3.jpg"]; 
           counter = 2;
       }
        else if(counter == 2) {
           myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Abe1.jpg"]; 
           counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your touchesBegan not working? What error is it giving?

Comment: You need to override the method.

Comment: Just copy and paste the method. Then make a counter in the interface.

Comment: Hmmm... Is the image full screen? If so you can delete that extra condition.

Comment: You might want to check if the user taps the cell then and use the rest of my logic.

Comment: no still i cant override touch method and i am in section view not row 
i did this
 if (indexPath.row == 0 )
 {
  NSLog(@"sdsdfs");
  
 } now ??

Comment: Don't overide touchesBegan override the tableView method.

Comment: now its working but its working on all cells when ever i touch even if upper cells then also image is changing

Comment: Did you take away the touches began? Just checking.

Comment: it dosent  matter whether touch-began is there or not  i tried both ways(with n without) but its cell issues any idea